# How to make a Python property also callable?

Tags: python, properties

I have

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    def x(self):
        return self._x

    def setx(self, value):
        self._x = value
```

which uses methods to set and get a state.

```
a = A()
a.setx(5)
print(a.x())
```

Now I thought about adding a property

```
class A:

    # as above

    x = property(x, setx)
```

which behaves like an attribute

```
a = A()
a.x = 5
print(a.x)
```

For legacy reasons the read access `x()` must also still work and unfortunately the name is the same as the planned property. This doesn't seem to work

```
a.x()
```

gives

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

which means the property strikes first.

Is there any way to make a property also callable so that `a.x()` returns what `a.x` would return when `x` is a property? Possible return values of the property are strings, numbers and lists of strings and numbers.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/594892/1536976) states that properties, members and methods all share the same namespace, so that might get complicated, but maybe there is a way.

Comment: Well, indeed no. You may try to add a method in `a.x` but then the value of `a.x` will change

Comment: The only way is to get the property to return something that is itself callable, but which behaves similarly to an integer otherwise. Django did something similar when converting the `User.is_authenticated` method to a property, by returning a "CallableBoolean" class.

Comment: You'd have to build a proxy object that adds a `__call__` method. That is **not easy** as you'd have to cover all possible uses of the value you return, including all  special method hooks, `isinstance()` or `type(..) is typeobj` tests, and immutability. I'd really try to avoid this if I were you. Make a clean break (no longer support code that calls) or don't use a property.

Comment: Must it *'still work'* for everyone, or can you supply two different interfaces depending upon the client? Consider adapting the interface for legacy clients.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The return values are strings, numbers, lists of strings and numbers, so a proxy might be possible, but I'm very reluctant about it and try to avoid it.